# Good motor supplier?

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, servo, sourcing

I'm looking to start a few different projects and stock up on some basic components - I was just wondering if anyone knows a good supplier of DC motors, stepper motors and servos?

I'm in vicinity of Sydney in Australia, so big pats on the back if they ship here. Thanks!

Comment: Try Oatley electronics; they've got heaps plus i/f hardware & controllers 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been most impressed with the [Pololu](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/category/21) range of motors and servos.

Their site has clear specs for each of the parts and other parts to accompany the motor.

Note: Gratuitous plug

[Little Bird Electronics](http://www.littlebirdelectronics.com/collections/robotics) is starting to get these in stock if you want cheaper shipping in Australia but it might be a while before the full range is in.

Comment: Thanks very much! I actually found out about chiphacker through Little Bird: I've ordered a few Arduino bits through LBE before, so it's awesome to hear they're getting motors in stock.

Answer (score 2):

Another good resource is [Anaheim Automation](http://anaheimautomation.com/) - especially if you're looking for a wide variety of stepper form factors at an excellent price.  While they don't do online ordering, they are very easy to deal with as a hobbyist on the phone.  They also provide CAD and full diagrams on their motor models, making it easy to determine what will fit in your project.

Full disclosure: I am not an employee of AA, but I am a satisfied customer =)

Comment: They look like a brilliant supplier, but postage to Australia may be a bit pricy. Great suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Even though they are in Victoria, you might consider http://www.oceancontrols.com.au. They have a few types of motors including some interesting stepper motors.

Answer (score 1):

American Science and Surplus!

http://www.sciplus.com/

Comment: Assuming they have what you need, and assuming you can figure out how to use them without documentation.  That's primarily what's kept me from AS&S.

Answer (score 1):

[Solarbotics](http://www.solarbotics.com/) has a nice selection of [Motors and accessories](http://www.solarbotics.com/motors%5Faccessories/).  They appear to ship internationally (from Canada).